# Replacement of missing values by median for all variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have to replace the missing value by the median for all variables.
I know how to do it for each variable separately.

```
df$x1=ifelse(is.na(df$x1),median(df$x1,na.rm=T),df$x1)
```

But i have 21 variables and replacing must be performed for 20 variables from x1-x20.
How to replace missing value for 20 variables at once?
I don't want create 20 strings.

Comment: Can't say exactly unless you post sample data, but you could likely gather it into long-shaped data, group by some variable, and do this operation once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::mutate_at` to replace missing values with `median` for that column. The `mutate_at` provides the flexibility (using `start_with`) to select columns starting with starting with `X`, for which rule will be applied.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("X")), funs(ifelse(is.na(.),median(., na.rm = TRUE),.)))

#    ID X1   X2
# 1   a  1 21.0
# 2   b  2 22.0
# 3   c  7 23.0  << X1 was missing
# 4   d  7 24.0  << X1 was missing
# 5   e  7 25.0  << X1 was missing
# 6   f  6 26.0
# 7   g  7 24.5  << X2 was missing
# 8   h  8 24.5  << X2 was missing
# 9   i  9 29.0
# 10  j 10 30.0
```

Sample Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=letters[1:10], X1 = 1:10, X2 = 21:30)
df$X1[3:5] <- NA
df$X2[7:8] <- NA

df
#    ID X1 X2
# 1   a  1 21
# 2   b  2 22
# 3   c NA 23
# 4   d NA 24
# 5   e NA 25
# 6   f  6 26
# 7   g  7 NA
# 8   h  8 NA
# 9   i  9 29
# 10  j 10 30
```

Comment: MKR, what if my last variable is text? Will this code work?

Comment: @San.O You can add additional condition as `ifelse(is.na(.) & is.numeric(.) ,median(., na.rm = TRUE),.))`. I have not tested it but should work.