# Replacing NA Values in a data frame with the median using a for loop

Tags: r

I have been trying to work out how to use a for loop to replace NA values in certain columns with the median of the column.
So far I have this:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(merged_df_edit3)){
  if(is.na(merged_df_edit3[,i]) == TRUE){
    assign(merged_df_edit3[,i],replace_na(median(merged_df_edit3[,i])))
  }
```

}

this works and runs, but gives of the warning:

> "In if (is.na(merged_df_edit3[, i]) == TRUE) { ... :   the condition
> has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

however, when I check the data frame it hasn't replaced any values at all.

The data I am using is mixed between numeric, date and character as is like this.
There are some blanks in the character columns but I do no need them filled.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~`date Column`,   ~`Numeric Column`,  ~`Character Column`,
  "1/1/2011",   123,    "Left",
  "1/2/2011",   124,    "Right",
  "1/3/2011",   125,    "Left",
  "1/4/2011",   NA,   "NA",
  "1/5/2011",   132,    "Right"
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you please include some code to generate the example dataset, as well as the code that loads the packages you use? `replace_na()` is not a base function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437198/replacement-of-missing-values-by-median-for-all-variables-in-r

Comment: It should be noted that `is.na` performs vectorized operation on its input. So it returns a logical vector the same length as the input. When yo put it into an `if` statement only the first element will be checked because `if` does not iterate over a vector and we need a `for` loop for that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is need for only one `for` loop and one `if` condition.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  if(is.numeric(df[[i]])){
    na <- is.na(df[[i]])
    df[na, i] <- median(df[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear Rui, I haven't thought about it this way. I think this is also a bit faster than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a loop, you could use `dplyr` which will probably be a bit more efficient:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
      mutate(across(where(is.numeric),function(x) {if_else(is.na(x),median(x,na.rm=T),x)}))
```

Comment: Since it is noted that only `NA` values in numeric column be replaced by the median of that column maybe using `where(is.numeric)` is a more appropriate choice for this problem than `everything()`.

Comment: My pleasure dear Waldi.

Comment: Thanks Waldi, ive never used the across function before!

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using a `for` loop here is a solution that might help you. It should be noted that I first check whether the column is numeric and then iterate over its rows to find the `NA` values.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~`date Column`,   ~`Numeric Column`,  ~`Character Column`,
  "1/1/2011",   123,    "Left",
  "1/2/2011",   124,    "Right",
  "1/3/2011",   125,    "Left",
  "1/4/2011",   NA,   "NA",
  "1/5/2011",   132,    "Right"
)

for(j in 1:ncol(df)) {
  if(is.numeric(df[[j]])) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      if(is.na(df[i, j])) {
        df[i, j] <- median(df[[j]], na.rm = TRUE)
      }
    }
  }
}
df

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  `date Column` `Numeric Column` `Character Column`
  <chr>                    <dbl> <chr>             
1 1/1/2011                  123  Left              
2 1/2/2011                  124  Right             
3 1/3/2011                  125  Left              
4 1/4/2011                  124. NA                
5 1/5/2011                  132  Right
```

The 4th element of `Numeric Column` has been replace by the median of that column.